# How to add many personalized sizes in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I would like to add many personalized sizes in Photoshop CC.

Someone knows where I can find the file with the personalized sizes created by user?

**Below the screen "New Document" with the personalized sizes created by user.**

**(File | New | Saved Tab)**

[image: New document with personalized sizes added by user]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot be positive since I don't know your platform or Photoshop version, but for me it is:

`C:\Users\Myname\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2018\Adobe Photoshop CC 2018 Settings\New Doc Sizes.json`

This file is easily editable, it is just json, sample follows:

```
{
"sections": [
    {
        "section": "user",
        "presets": [
            {
                "name": "Test_1",
                "group": "user",
                "width": 8.5,
                "height": 14.0,
                "units": "inchesUnit",
                "profile": "default",
                "resolution": 300.0,
                "resolutionUnits": "inchesUnit",
                "depth": 8,
                "scale": 1.0,
                "mode": "RGB",
                "fill": "white",
                "guides": [],
                "artboards": []
            },
            {
                "name": "Test_2",
                "group": "user",
                "width": 1600.0,
                "height": 1200.0,
                "units": "pixelsUnit",
                "profile": "none",
                "resolution": 72.0,
                "resolutionUnits": "inchesUnit",
                "depth": 8,
                "scale": 1.0,
                "mode": "RGB",
                "fill": "white",
                "guides": [],
                "artboards": [],
                "lastUsedTime": 1541501117008
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the file and now I can edit perfectly.

Comment: That's great, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Enter the size, resolution, color mode, etc. for a new document and then click the **Save Preset** button in the "New" dialog Window.

[image]

You can do this repeatedly for different configurations without ever having to leave the "new" dialog.

Comment: Yes this is true. It wasn't until after I found the "hardcore" way above that I realised the UI here is simply a pretty slick "editor" for that json file and likely the easier way to do it! That said, perhaps the OP wants to create 1000, in which case the json (maybe via excel) would be useful I suppose. Also good to know where to back them up or share them from.